# Does rotation the polarization of one twin photon rotate the other?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, bells-inequality, non-linear-optics

After a nonlinear crystal there are two photons in HH+VV state. What happens to the state if one of the photons in the pair is rotated? Does the state stay the same or it flips to HV+VH?

Comment: it stays the same!

Answer (score 0):

You should say more specifically what you mean with "the state if one of the photons is rotated" Without further explanation one would assume that changing a HH+VV state into HV+VH is exactly what you describe in the first place, so then the question is self-answering: yes.

Actually you have a case here of two fully entangled qubits. They form a space described by 4 basis vectors (for instance the 4 [Bell states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_state#Bell_basis) with a well-chosen phase factor: $|\Phi^+\rangle,\ i|\Phi^-\rangle,\ i|\Psi^+\rangle$, and $|\Psi^-\rangle$ could be used). Only transformations with real coefficients are then allowed to mix them in this space of maximally entangled states. So the symmetry is SO(4). That is essentially the same as SU(2) x SU(2) (see [SE question 179983](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179983), [physicsforums](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/meaning-of-so-4-su-2-xsu-2.446309/)). It is possible to use those two SU(2) factors to describe separate rotations of the two separate particles.

This can even be visualized in 4D-to-3D stereographic projection, with the one-particle SU(2) actions as "double-rotations" in SO(4), moving the state around a Clifford torus [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotations_in_4-dimensional_Euclidean_space). If you analyze it in depth, you find that not only (as you ask in your question) the state is definitely changed by rotating just one particle, but you can reach *every maximally entangled state* by rotating just one of the particles! That may sound at first a bit paradoxical, how can it be that the other state needs no adjustment at all?! But every maximally entangled state can be written as:
$$
\begin{align}
  |\psi\rangle = & \ e^{i \phi} \ \frac{1}{\sqrt2} \ \big(\ |0\rangle_A\ |\xi\rangle_B +  |1\rangle_A\ |\xi^{\perp}\rangle_{B} \ \big), \tag{Eq1} \\[10pt]
\mbox{where}\quad  |\xi\rangle = & \ \begin{pmatrix} \alpha \\ \beta \end{pmatrix}, \quad \mbox{with} \quad |\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2=1, \\[5pt]
\mbox{and}\quad  |\xi^{\perp}\rangle = & \ \begin{pmatrix} -\beta^* \\ \alpha^*  \end{pmatrix} 
\end{align}
$$
So to reach an arbitrary maximally entangled state (up to a phase factor) you can always stay within the form of [Eq1] and doing so only requires particle B to be transformed. It's also easy to show that after any transformation on particle B you can "undo" the effect it had on the total state, by applying an appropriate transformation to particle A.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what happens all the time due to environmental influences and what quantum cryptography tries to prevent in practice. This cancels the correlation between the two particles. In short, the second particle remains unaffected by changes to the first particle.